# javascript ternary operator "chaining"

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm trying to write something like this with a ternary operator (needed because of jsx syntax constraints)

```
if(!this.state.msg) {
    if(this.state.ask.length != 0) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
       // do stuff
    }
    if(this....) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
      // ...
    }
} else {
    //nothing
}
```

So I tried this dumb

```
   !this.state.msg ? this.state.ask.length != 0 ? //do stuff : "" this.state... ? //do stuff : //do other stuff : //nothing
```

But it's obviously not the right way to go.

Any help very welcomed. thanks in advance.

Comment: just replace saying if with "?" and else with ":" . OI will write it up for you.

Comment: Your original code is not "ternary", because the initial `if` has no `else`.

Comment: true I edited, but still not working

Comment: Please don't do that

Comment: jsx syntax doesn't let me other choices

Comment: Good to know, bad to do.

Comment: Yeah maybe I should just not do this work in the jsx part... true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your true branch has two components; you can separate them with commas (parenthesized, since the comma has weaker associativity than the ternary operator). So

```
!this.state.msg ?
  (
    this.state.ask.length != 0 ? /*stuff*/ : /*stuff*/,
    this... ? /* stuff */ : /* ... */
  ) : /* nothing */
```

Or, since the `else` branch is doing "nothing", you could replace the ternary operator at the top level with a simple and:

```
!this.state.msg &&
  (
    this.state.ask.length != 0 ? /*stuff*/ : /*stuff*/,
    this... ? /* stuff */ : /* ... */
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong in your assertion that JSX limits you in this way - read this [doc page](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) and you will see that you can use something like this:

```
{(() => {
// My awesome multi-step code
})()}
```

Comment: @rollingBalls BTW, never heard of JSX until your comment and post. So, of course, I googled it, and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it'd help to add another perspective. It's very rare that you would actually *need* to use the ternary operator with JSX. In this case, I would consider moving all of this logic out into a separate function.

```
helperFunction: function() {
  if(!this.state.msg) {
    if(this.state.ask.length != 0) {
      // return stuff
    } else {
      // return stuff
    }

    if(this....) {
      // return stuff
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  } else {
    // nothing
  }
}
```

Then you'd be able to use your helper function from inside your render method.

```
React.createClass({
  helperFunction: function() {
    // ...
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
       {this.helperFunction()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Your helper function can return values that can be used for attributes, or it can return other JSX components. Often I find it helpful to move code out of patterns that look like this:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    condition === 'example' ?
      <MyComponent attr={this.props.example} onChange={this.props.onChange} /> :
      <MyOtherComponent attr={this.state.example} onChange={this.state.onChange}/>
   );
}
```

To code that looks like this:

```
helper: function(condition) {
  if(condition === 'example') {
    return (
      <MyComponent attr={this.props.example} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
    );
  }

  else {
    return (
      <MyOtherComponent attr={this.state.example} onChange={this.state.onChange}/>
    );
  }
},
render: function() {
  return this.helper(condition);
}
```

Or even better in the case of string equality checking.

```
helper: function(condition) {
  const default = <MyOtherComponent attr={this.state.example} onChange={this.state.onChange}/>

  const conditions = {
    example: <MyComponent attr={this.props.example} onChange={this.props.onChange} />,
    example2: <MyComponent attr={this.props.example} onChange={this.props.onChange} />,
    example3: <MyComponent attr={this.props.example} onChange={this.props.onChange} />,
  };

  return conditions[condition] || default;
},
render: function() {
  return this.helper(condition);
}
```

This way gives you most of the power of a switch statement, but terser syntax too, it lets you elegantly select from a large number of conditional components. The same code written with if statements (regular or ternary) would be much more verbose.

Comment: Yes that's what i usually do, actually a part of my code is made like that, I was extending a part of jsx and was lazy to take it out ... =/ But yeah right way to go for sure

Answer (score 1):

For verbosity, clarity of expression and maintainability, I would not recommend converting if-else to ternary expression. Try to keep your code simple even at the expense of few extra lines.

Here it is if you just want to learn

```
!this.state.msg ? 
  (this.state.ask.length != 0 ? //do if stuff : //do else stuff),
  (this.some == 0 ? //do 2nd if stuff : //do 2nd else stuff)
:
```

Answer (score 0):

Visualizing it helps.

```
    !this.state.msg ?
                        ? this.state.ask.length != 0) 
                              // do stuff
                        :
                              // do stuff
                     :
                     this.... ?
                               //do stuff
                              :
                                // ...
```

Comment: I always just visualize them, and swap out the statements. That is all it is, is short hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the same logic as the original code. You're executing the second part when `this.state.ask.length != 0` is not true, but in the original code, the second part is executed as a second statement when that condition **is** true.

Comment: I realized afterwards, and thought they were just asking how to interpret logic. I should remove this actually. Thanks

Comment: In fact I don't think there is a way to execute in a ternary statement without splitting it. Actually I splitted it so it's legal ternary syntax now and it works. If there is a solution to respect the initial logic please let me know but for now this is the right answer for me. thanks.